Inline vs Function-based Swapping (First Missing Positive)
I am trying to solve this leetcode problem: First Missing Positive. However, I am facing a problem while performing the swap.
I referred to the solution here.
So instead of having a helper function like this to perform the swap,
class Solution:
    def firstMissingPositive(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        def swap_elements(index1, index2):
            nums[index1], nums[index2] = nums[index2], nums[index1]

        list_length = len(nums)
      
        for i in range(list_length):
            while 1 <= nums[i] <= list_length and nums[i] != nums[nums[i] - 1]:
                swap_elements(i, nums[i] - 1)

        for i in range(list_length):
            if i + 1 != nums[i]:
                return i + 1
      
        return list_length + 1

I tried to perform an inline swap like this
class Solution:
    def firstMissingPositive(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        list_length = len(nums)
      
        for i in range(list_length):
            while 1 <= nums[i] <= list_length and nums[i] != nums[nums[i] - 1]:
                nums[i], nums[nums[i] - 1] = nums[nums[i] - 1], nums[i]
              
        for i in range(list_length):
            if i + 1 != nums[i]:
                return i + 1
      
        return list_length + 1

Both approaches use the same logic, but the second does not work for some inputs.
Example: Given the input [3,4,-1,1], the first approach will change the nums like this
[-1, 4, 3, 1] --> [-1, 1, 3, 4] --> [1, -1, 3, 4]
but the second approach will cause an infinite while loop
[-1, 4, 3, 1] --> [4, 1, 3, 1] --> [4, 4, 3, 1] --> [4, 1, 3, 1] --> [4, 4, 3, 1]...

You just need to "store" the index and reuse it for the second part of the swap:
class Solution:
    def firstMissingPositive(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        list_length = len(nums)
      
        for i in range(list_length):
            while 1 <= nums[i] <= list_length and nums[i] != nums[nums[i] - 1]:
                index = nums[i] - 1
                nums[i], nums[index] = nums[index], nums[i]
              
        for i in range(list_length):
            if i + 1 != nums[i]:
                return i + 1
      
        return list_length + 1


Note that the function-call version implicitly stores this index with the implicit assignment of nums[i] - 1 to the parameter index1.

of course, no argument here :)

Sorry, that was more a clarifying comment for the OP, to show why the explicit function call was different from the inlined version.
